# How to convert an image to CV_32F type in IJ-OpenCV library

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, imagej

I wrote a filter with OpenCV library and want to install it as a plugin into Fiji app. So, for this reason I am converting the OpenCV codes to IJ-OpenCV. 
I have imported org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_core.CvType, but it is different from opencv's CvType.

What I want is to write the below line with IJ-OpenCV.

```
img.converTo(img, CvType.CV_32F)
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I have found CV_32F type. Unlike OpenCV java, it is located in opencv_core not in CvType.